# How to invoke code in main thread on java or kotlin?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, coroutine

I'm trying to use spigot event which not supports multithread with multithread plugin.

**I've tried:**

Using Coroutine in kotlin works fine with Default dispatcher but in main dispatcher, It throws exception about main dispatcher is missing(I impl coroutines-core and also coroutines-core-jvm).

I found code using `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` in SO but I cannot use while(true) loop on main thread.

I found code works fine with C#.

```cs
this.Invoke(() => { }));
```

Is any code exists for me?

Comment: I think on JVM you need the specific coroutines library for the UI system you’re using, e.g. Swing or JavaFX.

Comment: This isn't really possible in a generic case. So called "main thread" is always related to some specific framework/technology that runs an event loop internally. We can even have multiple main threads in the same application. Anyway, this is a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is your real problem that you try to solve? If you want to create an event loop for your own use then create an executor with `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` and optionally convert it to a coroutine dispatcher (if you want to use coroutines).

Answer (score 0):

I found code for spigot,

```kotlin
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(JavaPlugin, Runnable {
    }
}, 1L, 1L)
```

which calls runnable every one tick. And I found that it not exists on default JVM functions.